# Create a object hierarchy from a list of folder locations

Tags: c#, string, recursion, linq-to-objects, hierarchy

I have a list of locations as strings;

```
locA/locB
locA/locB/locH
locC/locD/locE
locC/locD/locE/locK
locF/locG
```

I've been trying to create an object that uses the same structure as the list of locations passed to it;

e.g. Something like..

```
var myHObject=CreateHeirarchicalObjectFromList(myStringListOfLocations);
```

I'm having problems looping through the list without almost doing it manually with loads of loops. Is there an easier way, maybe recursion?

I want to end up with an object like this;

```
.locA
    .locB
         .locH
.locC
    .locD
         .locE
              .locK
.locF
     .locG
```

That I can use to create a visual hierarchy.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Precise your question

Comment: I need an object, based on a passed array of folder locations, to create a explorer type structure of a virtual filestore. The object will contain references to objects within the filestore, but the initial structure is determined by a list of locations.

Comment: To confirm, is your example representative of the issue you have?  Do you want an example of how to do recursion, or do you want an example on how to resolve your list above?  Your list shows a 0-to-1 mapping both for parent and child elements, is that intended?

Comment: Also, there is no root object on your example list, there is 3 independant hierarchies.  Should an example method create a root or return a list of hierarchically arranged objects?

Comment: You need a tree: [Tree<T>: Implementing a Non-Binary Tree in C#](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/)

Comment: I see it as being a Folder Object, with a Name property and a childFolders property which contains other folder objects deeper in the heirarchy. Much in the same way as the Directory object.
I think a better example would be recreating a website structure from a list of relative URLs.

Comment: Thanks Paolo, thats perfect. I was having a headache trying to work out the correct terminology, but you have hit the nail on the head. Rephrase it as an answer and I'll give you a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prob not the best but knocked up in LinqPad, will reformat in a sec..

```
    void Main()
    {
        var strings = new string[]{"locA/locB","locA/locB/locH",
                         "locC/locD/locE","locC/locD/locE/locK","locF/locG"};

        var folders = Folder.Parse(strings);

        folders.Dump();
    }


    public class Folder
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Folder> Folders { get; internal set; }

        public Folder()
        {
            Folders = new List<Folder>();
        }
        //Presume that each string will be folder1/folder2/folder3
        public static IEnumerable<Folder> Parse(IEnumerable<string> locations)
        {
            var folders = new List<Folder>();
            foreach (string location in locations)
            {
                string[] parts = location.Split('/');
                Folder current = null;
                foreach (string part in parts)
                {
                    var useFolders = current != null ? 
                               current.Folders : folders;
                    current = useFolders.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == part) ?? new Folder() { Name = part };
                    if (!useFolders.Contains(current)) { useFolders.Add(current); }
                }
            }
            return folders;
        }
    }
```